# Logitech G-KEY MACRO SDK(C#): can't enter the profile when I pressed my mouse button

Tags: c#, logitech

SDK link: https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/developer-lab.html

It can create a profile in the LGS, but if I debug in **GkeySDKCallback()** it can't enter it when I pressed my mouse button.

I sent an email to Logitech Dev Support regarding this, but have not received anything back at this time.
Here is my code [2 files]

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logitceh
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool usingCallback = false;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            Start();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnDestroy();
        }

        void Start()
        {
            usingCallback = true; 
            if (usingCallback)
            {
                LogitechGSDK.logiGkeyCB cbInstance = new
                LogitechGSDK.logiGkeyCB(this.GkeySDKCallback);
                LogitechGSDK.LogiGkeyInitWithoutContext(cbInstance);
            }
            else
            {
                LogitechGSDK.LogiGkeyInitWithoutCallback();
            }
        }



        void OnUpdate()
        {
            if (!usingCallback)
            {
                for (int index = 6; index <= LogitechGSDK.LOGITECH_MAX_MOUSE_BUTTONS; index++)
                {
                    if (LogitechGSDK.LogiGkeyIsMouseButtonPressed(index) == 1)
                    {
                        //  Code    to  handle  what    happens on  gkey    pressed on  mouse
                    }
                }
                for (int index = 1; index <= LogitechGSDK.LOGITECH_MAX_GKEYS; index++)
                {
                    for (int mKeyIndex = 1; mKeyIndex <= LogitechGSDK.LOGITECH_MAX_M_STATES;
            mKeyIndex++)
                    {
                        if (LogitechGSDK.LogiGkeyIsKeyboardGkeyPressed(index, mKeyIndex) == 1)
                        {
                            //  Code    to  handle  what    happens on  gkey    pressed on  keyboard/headset
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void GkeySDKCallback(LogitechGSDK.GkeyCode gKeyCode, String gKeyOrButtonString, IntPtr context)
        {
            if (gKeyCode.keyDown == 1)
            {
                if (gKeyCode.mouse == 1)
                {
                    //  Code    to  handle  what    happens on  gkey    released    on  mouse
                }
                else
                {
                    //  Code    to  handle  what    happens on  gkey released   on  keyboard/headset
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (gKeyCode.mouse == 1)
                {
                    //  Code    to  handle  what    happens on  gkey    pressed on  mouse
                }
                else
                {
                    //  Code    to  handle  what    happens on  gkey    pressed on  keyboard
                }
            }
        }
        void OnDestroy()
        {
            //Free G-Keys   SDKs    before  quitting    the game
            LogitechGSDK.LogiGkeyShutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

**LogitechGSDK.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System;
public class LogitechGSDK
{
    //G-KEY SDK
    public const int LOGITECH_MAX_MOUSE_BUTTONS = 20;
    public const int LOGITECH_MAX_GKEYS = 29;
    public const int LOGITECH_MAX_M_STATES = 3;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    public struct GkeyCode
    {
        public ushort complete;
        //  index   of  the G   key or  mouse   button, for example,    6   for G6  or  Button  6
        public int keyIdx
        {
            get
            {
                return complete & 255;
            }
        }
        //  key up  or  down,   1   is  down,   0   is  up
        public int keyDown
        {
            get
            {
                return (complete >> 8) & 1;
            }
        }
        //  mState  (1, 2   or  3   for M1, M2  and M3)
        public int mState
        {
            get
            {
                return (complete >> 9) & 3;
            }
        }
        //  indicate    if  the Event   comes   from    a   mouse,  1   is  yes,    0   is  no.
        public int mouse
        {
            get
            {
                return (complete >> 11) & 15;
            }
        }
        //  reserved1
        public int reserved1
        {
            get
            {
                return (complete >> 15) & 1;
            }
        }
        //  reserved2
        public int reserved2
        {
            get
            {
                return (complete >> 16) & 131071;
            }
        }
    }
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void logiGkeyCB(GkeyCode gkeyCode,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]String gkeyOrButtonString, IntPtr context);    //  ??
    [DllImport(@"C:/DLL/LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int LogiGkeyInitWithoutCallback();
    [DllImport(@"C:/DLL/LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int LogiGkeyInitWithoutContext(logiGkeyCB gkeyCB);
    [DllImport(@"C:/DLL/LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int LogiGkeyIsMouseButtonPressed(int buttonNumber);
    [DllImport(@"C:/DLL/LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr LogiGkeyGetMouseButtonString(int buttonNumber);
    public static String LogiGkeyGetMouseButtonStr(int buttonNumber)
    {
        String str =
        Marshal.PtrToStringUni(LogiGkeyGetMouseButtonString(buttonNumber));
        return str;
    }
    [DllImport(@"C:/DLL/LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int LogiGkeyIsKeyboardGkeyPressed(int gkeyNumber, int
    modeNumber);
    [DllImport(@"C:/DLL/LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper")]
    private static extern IntPtr LogiGkeyGetKeyboardGkeyString(int gkeyNumber, int
    modeNumber);
    public static String LogiGkeyGetKeyboardGkeyStr(int gkeyNumber, int modeNumber)
    {
        String str =
        Marshal.PtrToStringUni(LogiGkeyGetKeyboardGkeyString(gkeyNumber, modeNumber));
        return str;
    }
    [DllImport(@"C:/DLL/LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void LogiGkeyShutdown();
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to register the callback event with a "+="?

Comment: I am according to Logitech SDK write the  LogitechGSDK.cs

Comment: I downloaded the SDK and read the c#Instructions.pdf.  Make sure you do either step 3 (32 bit) or 4 (64 bit)  and end of document.  I can't tell from your comments if the issue is the device or the software. It is possible that the device isn't installed properly.So I would use Device Manager and check if the device is installed and not colored yellow which would indicate an issue.I would also make sure you are entering all the methods by stepping through code (or adding break points).If you are stuck inside one of the SDK methods using VS menu Debug : BreakAll will tell where code is stopped.

Comment: the device is installed and not yellow exclamation ico

Comment: You need to do more debugging to see if the software is running through all the configuration code.

Comment: The only thing I found was : For mice with on-board modes (G600 and G300), the SDK only works if the mouse is not in on-board mode.

Comment: I have 2 mouse.G302 and G502. They all use 'Automatic Game Detection'.When I run the program it just can create a profile,the SDK methods not work

Comment: I would contact Logitech.  It may be the SDK do not support your mouses.

Comment: It may not be useful.I sent an email to Logitech Dev Support,but have not received anything back

Comment: Did the Logitech reply to your message?

Comment: Half year has passed.  Did the Logitech reply to your message?